# Typeof number is false

Tags: javascript, types

I have a function that asserts the type of a value amongst other things. the problem is, when checking for the typeof a number, it doesn't give the expected result
For example, a contrived version of the function may look like this

Now, some of the confusion comes from the fact that if I log the type of the val, it prints `number`, but when that is compared against a string of "number", the comparison is false.
More confusion occurs when it works perfectly for bool's and strings.

Example usage of the function:

```js
function CheckType(val, expectedType) {
  return (typeof val == expectedType);
}


console.log(CheckType(10, "number")); // false
console.log(CheckType(true, "boolean")); // true
console.log(CheckType("Hello World", "string")); // true;
```

EDIT: I've tried with === and still did not work

Comment: What is `Assert`? Maybe you should use `===` instead of it?

Comment: I'm getting `true` for all three. Can you please post your complete actual code?

Comment: Works for me, too. Probably some side-effect in part of the code you didn't provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least you need to return the result of checking.

```js
function checkType(val, expectedType){
    return typeof val === expectedType;
}

console.log(checkType(10, "number"));
console.log(checkType(true, "boolean"));
console.log(checkType("Hello World", "string"));
```

Comment: Still it won't give `false`.

Comment: @Bergi, we still do not know, what `Assert` is doing. and without returning something, it should return `undefined`.

Comment: OP stated "*the comparison is false*", i.e. `Assert` receiving `false`. Doesn't look like a problem with return values - but yes, we really don't know.

Comment: Using the === seemed to fix it!